# LABVIEW - How to create a csv file with string, double and integer?

Tags: cluster-computing, labview

I'm working in LABView and I want to create a csv file with an header string, 8192 double type values and a integer type value at the end. I tried with the clusters but it seems not work and so I'm stucked. My situation is the following:
[image]
If I connect the output cluster with the "Create Spreadsheet" vi it gives me incompatible type error and same if I use the "Convert Cluster to Array" vi.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Convert all the double arrays to string arrays in the format you want and make your input one big string array, in that way you can also included the header. So the code would look like this, it is an older version of labview but works the same way.

[image]

And the result array that gets written to file looks likes this:

[image]